# Is it possible to qualify for Boston or break 3 hours in a marathon with only weekend training?

Tags: marathon, running-training-plan, half-marathon

Is it possible to qualify for Boston or break 3 hours in a marathon with only weekend training?

Currently running +10 miles twice a week on the weekend and I am wondering how far that might take me to breaking or approaching a 3 hour marathon.

If not marathon then what about getting a 1:20 min or better half marathon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think breaking 3 hours or better for a marathon or 1.20 for half is very unlikely on training just at the weekends.  Of course it depends on your starting point, and if you do lots of other cardio work during the week.

Even if you are extremely talented, you still have to train to get the good results.  I know many people who run sub 3 hour marathons, and have done so myself on a number of occasions.  All train hard with a minimum or 4-5 training days a week.  The marathon is to be respected, you can't just turn up and expect it to be ok.

Comment: Fastest weekend only training times were 1:43 for a half and 4:22 for a full. Sep '14 started running faster short runs during the middle of the week and longer slower runs on the weekend. 3-5 days a week. In practice I hit 1:32 for a half and 3:36 for a full that winter. I'd say no is the right answer now :)